# How to create osd for Ceph on loop device

Tags: ceph

I'm playing with Ceph in Vagrant environment & trying to create some minimal cluster.
I have two nodes: 'master' & 'slave'
Master as admin, monitor, manager.
Slave for OSD.

I'm following the official ceph deploy guides & facing the problem with OSD creation.
On slave node I created some 10Gb loop device & mounted it to /media/vdevice
then on master node I've tried to create OSD:

```
ceph-deploy osd create slave1:loop0
```

It fails with:

```
...
[slave1][WARNIN]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ceph_disk/main.py", line 956, in verify_not_in_use
[slave1][WARNIN]     raise Error('Device is mounted', dev)
[slave1][WARNIN] ceph_disk.main.Error: Error: Device is mounted: /dev/loop0
[slave1][ERROR ] RuntimeError: command returned non-zero exit status: 1
[ceph_deploy.osd][ERROR ] Failed to execute command: /usr/sbin/ceph-disk -v prepare --cluster ceph --fs-type xfs -- /dev/loop0
[ceph_deploy][ERROR ] GenericError: Failed to create 1 OSDs
```

In case of unmounted loop0 it fails with:

```
[slave1][WARNIN] ceph_disk.main.Error: Error: /dev/loop0 device size (0M) is not big enough for data
[slave1][ERROR ] RuntimeError: command returned non-zero exit status: 1
[ceph_deploy.osd][ERROR ] Failed to execute command: /usr/sbin/ceph-disk -v prepare --cluster ceph --fs-type xfs -- /dev/loop0
[ceph_deploy][ERROR ] GenericError: Failed to create 1 OSDs
```

Which is make sense as the actual storage is not binded to the system.
So how can we prepare the storage for OSD?

Comment: When unmounting `loop0` did you also execute `losetup -d /dev/loop0`? Could you try running `losetup /dev/loop0 /your/10GB/file` again and check if ceph-deploy would fail with the same message?

Comment: @DmitriChubarov thanks for the hint! In my case I've just mounted the file to mount point but haven't associated it with loop0. So I've just unmount it & executed the 'sudo losetup /dev/loop0 vdrive.img'. After that OSD has been created.

Comment: Ok, I'd write it up as an answer then. It seems to be something that other people might encounter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ceph requires a block device on an OSD. To turn a disk image file into a loopback block device you can use the `losetup` utility.

```
sudo losetup /dev/loop0 /your/10GB/file.img
```

This command attaches the disk image file to the `/dev/loop0` device node creating a loopback block device that can be used with Ceph.

If you need to detach the image file from the device node you can execute

```
sudo losetup -d /dev/loop0
```

Note that by default Ceph reserve 100 MB per device, so you have to make sure that your image file size is greater than that. You could create an suitable image file with

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/cephfs/vdisk.img count=1 bs=10G
```

Comment: 2021-08-03 13:49:41.211459 W | inventory: skipping device "loop0". unsupported diskType loop

Comment: loop device isn't supported in ceph now